# Tooltips/Hover over shows ??? - when missing value - how to suppress the ??? and leave it blank or '-'

Tags: python, tooltip, bokeh

I am plotting geo location of some events, if there is location with only one event the second one appears as ???.
How to suppress the ??? or change to '-' if there is missing value?
Or if the event happens more than one time under same location, how to display once?

Here is example of the output:

[image]

And here is the graph code:

```
tile_provider = get_provider(CARTODBPOSITRON)
output_file('Geological_Disasters.html')
curdoc().theme = 'dark_minimal'

tooltips = [('Volcano Location', '@{Volcano Name}'),
        ('Earthquake Location', '@place'),
       ]
p = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=600,
           x_range=(world_lon1, world_lon2), y_range=(world_lat1, world_lat2),
           x_axis_type="mercator", y_axis_type="mercator",
           tools="pan, box_select, zoom_in, zoom_out, save, reset, hover, box_zoom",
           tooltips=tooltips,
           title='Geological Disasters')

p.add_tile(tile_provider)
# 1
p.circle(x="MercatorX", y="MercatorY",size=12,fill_color="dodgerblue", 
   line_color="dodgerblue",
              source=volcano19_20)

#2
p.circle(x="MercatorX", y="MercatorY", size=3,fill_color="red", line_color="red",
     line_alpha=0.1,fill_alpha=0.1,source=earthquakes19_20)
show(p)
```

Comment: That happens when you specify a column name in the tooltip that does not exist in the `ColumnDataSource`. In this case, the `@place` is asking to print values from a `"place"` column, which evidently does not exist in the `source` you pass to the glyph.

Comment: @bigreddot both columns 'place' and 'Volcano name' exist, but under some locations that appear on the map only one of these events exist, other can be "null". I wonder if I can 'suppress' the null value that currently appears as ??? with blank or '-' for example.

Comment: You could try a [`CustomJSHover`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/tools.html#bokeh.models.CustomJSHover) for those fields.